# What is this boot-like thing buried in the first desert level?

Tags: castle-crashers

I've just gotten to the desert levels in Castle Crashers yesterday.

In the very first level, you get to pick up a shovel which you can use to dig up various things buried in the sand (marked by small black Xs on the floor).
One of the things I managed to dig up looked sort of like a black boot with green laces (I'd describe it better, but I have no idea what it is, exactly. It's more than possible that it isn't a boot at all, perhaps a some sort of armor?). Once I walked over it to pick it up it simply disappeared with no apparent effect.

So my question is, what is the purpose of this mysterious item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a boot.  It doesn't do anything.  I mean you can't expect to dig up treasure EVERYWHERE, right?  You honestly can't do anything with it.  :(

The boot appears in a few places around the game, but that's the only one I can remember off the top of my head.

Comment: I see. While this makes sense in the real world, I find it to be extremely silly from a gameplay perspective.

Comment: Many things in Castle Crashers are silly, even from a gameplay perspective.  :P  That's part of what makes it so amusing.